# Yolo v8 Training on Nano dataset not working

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

I'm trying to train a yolov8 nano model with the following py script:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
 
# Load the model.
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
 
# Training.
results = model.train(
   data='pothole.yaml',
   imgsz=1280,
   epochs=10,
   batch=8,
   name='yolov8n_v8_50e'
)
```

However, I run into the following error about 5 minutes into running the script:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=233, connect=233, read=240, redirect=240, status=240)) after connection broken by 'NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x2a093e6d0>: Failed to resolve 'api.clear.ml' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")': /auth.login
```

Any suggestions? I've already tried updating urllib3 and ultralytics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems to be related to incorrect setup with ClearML. If you don't need it, just uninstall like this:

```
pip uninstall clearml
```

You can set it up again later, but you probably don't even need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the clearml logging by set to false the parameter shown in the following pic! You can find it in the ultralytics folder.

[image: clear ml param]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I used the pothole zipped dataset from [here](https://public.roboflow.com/object-detection/pothole/1) and the corresponding `data.yaml`):

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml')  # build a new model from scratch
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

# train the model (run on GPU, e.g., on colab)
results = model.train(data='data.yaml', epochs=3)
# Starting training for 3 epochs...
#
#  Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
#   1/3      2.59G      1.667       2.68      1.544          7        640: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:14<00:00,  2.09it/s]
#            Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:03<00:00,  1.65it/s]
#              all        133        330      0.885     0.0515      0.224      0.126
#
#  Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size 
#   2/3      2.36G      1.507      1.927      1.375          2        640: 100%| ██████████| 30/30 [00:10<00:00,  2.99it/s]
#            Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:01<00:00,  3.53it/s]
#              all        133        330       0.59      0.258      0.312      0.159
#
#  Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
#   3/3      2.24G      1.453       1.75      1.347          2        640: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:10<00:00,  2.85it/s]
#            Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:01<00:00,  3.35it/s]
#              all        133        330      0.682      0.561      0.606      0.332
```

Once the model is fine-tuned on the pothole images, we can use the model to predict the potholes in the following test image:

[image]

```
# predict on an image
results = model('test.jpg') 

# plot the bounding boxes of potholes predicted
for r in results:
    im_array = r.plot()  # plot a BGR numpy array of predictions
    im = Image.fromarray(im_array[..., ::-1])  # RGB PIL image
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

[image]